# iphone5(s) with iOS screen layout become short ，like 3.5 inch UI

Tags: ios7

I created an app for iphone5(s) with iOS7, but my app screen has become very short. However it shows on the the 3.5 UI(iphone4). I do not know why，please help me.

[image: phone image]

Answer (score 0):

Set your launch screen. Default is LaunchScreen.xib

[image]